# Is try/catch/finally an expression in scala ? if yes how and when does finally get executed?

Tags: scala

I wrote some code and i am a bit surprised by it. I'm specifically using try/catch/finally just to understand how it works in scala.

I am surprised but it is seems that try/catch/finally is actually an expression in scala ? Is it new or i miss something ? To some degree being functional i can understand that, but those are keyword in the language, i don't see the function that defines them.

Also in that code i do not understand why finally does not contribute to the return type. Only the catch and try do contribute to the return type. Hence i am not sure when exactly is finally executed.

Can someone explain or point me to the specification for that statement so i understand it. Again i know using the Try type is def the way to go but i just want to understand what is going on in here.

```
def createTripleList(msg: String): List[String] = {

  val outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream

  try {
    val model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()
    val jld = model.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBytes()), null, "JSON-LD")
    jld.write(outStream, "N-TRIPLE", null)
    model.close()
    outStream.toString.split("\n").toList
  }
  catch {
    case e:Throwable => println(s"Could not parse JsonLd: ${e.toString}"); List.empty[String]
  }
  finally {outStream.close()}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the **Scala Language Specification**.

> "A try expression is of the form try { b } catch h".
>
> "Let pt be the expected type of the try expression. The block b is expected to conform to pt. The handler h is expected conform to type  scala.PartialFunction[scala.Throwable, pt]. The type of the try expression is the weak least upper bound of the type of b and the result type of h".
>
> "A try expression try { b } finally e evaluates the block b. If evaluation of b does not cause an exception to be thrown, the expression e is evaluated. If an exception is thrown during evaluation of e, the evaluation of the try expression is aborted with the thrown exception. If no exception is thrown during evaluation of e, the result of b is returned as the result of the try expression".
>
> "If an exception is thrown during evaluation of b, the finally block e is also evaluated. If another exception e is thrown during evaluation of e, evaluation of the try expression is aborted with the thrown exception. If no exception is thrown during evaluation of e, the original exception thrown in b is re-thrown once evaluation of e has completed. The block b is expected to conform to the expected type of the try expression. The finally expression e is expected to conform to type Unit".
>
> -- [Source](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#try-expressions).

## TL; DR

No matter what happens, the **finally block** is always executed and it is expected to be of type `Unit` - that means it does not affect the return type of the expression.
However, the return type of a `try / catch` is  *"weak least upper bound"* of both the return type of the **try block** `b` and the return type of the **exception handler** `h`.